# kafka ingests data in different topics

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

My java producer is producing messages based on the topic to the Kafka cluster which has 3 brokers, everything is set to default properties except max.messages to 100mb. sometimes Kafka ingests it to a different topic topic-a message is getting pushed to the topic-b and vice-versa, so I have set 1s delay in producer while publishing the message thinking of more network calls(50K/per day)still messages are shuffled across. should I increase the num.network.threads or what would be the optimal solution.

Comment: Can you show some code? I do not understand how a 1s delay and other configurations should be the reason that your producer is sending messages to wrong topics. Could you maybe give an example of what you are observing?

Comment: Your producer code explicitly refers to a topic name, so are you sure there's not something else producing to other topics?